# Замена подстрок в файле определённое количество раз

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, replace, замена

Вопрос, возможно, некорректный, но решение найти не удалось:
Есть к примеру такой файл:

```
{
    "xxxxxxxx": "present/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxx": {
        "xxxxxxx": "present/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxx": "present/xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы заменить слово "present" на "test:present", причём сделать это ровно столько раз сколько нужно. 
То-есть, если нужно 2 раза, то результат должен быть таким:

```
{
    "xxxxxxxx": "test:present/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxx": {
        "xxxxxxx": "test:present/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxx": "present/xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Изначально неизвестен ни размер файла, ни кол-во искомых строк.
Пробовал с помощью String::replaceFirst в цикле, однако за два прохода, оно изменит одну и ту же строку, так как одна содержит другую: `present` -> `test:present` -> `test:test:present`.
На данный момент мой код выглядит так:

```java
String writable = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for(int z = 0; z < stepOnFile; ++z) {
   writable = writable.replaceFirst("present", "test:present");
}
```

stepOnFile - это, как раз кол-во повторов.

Comment: Боюсь в этом и проблема.Таких файлов предполагается несколько сотен, каждый от 1 до 5 мб. Не хочется замедлять программу... Я думал об использовании регулярных выражений, но решение не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public static String replaceTimes(Pattern pattern, String replacement,
                                  String input, int times) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < times && matcher.find(); i++) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(out, replacement);
    }

    return matcher.appendTail(out).toString();
}
```

```java
String text = "{\n" +
        "    \"xxxxxxxx\": \"present/xxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\n" +
        "    \"xxxxxxx\": {\n" +
        "        \"xxxxxxx\": \"present/xxxxxxxxxxxx\",\n" +
        "        \"xxxxxxx\": \"present/xxxxxxxxxx\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("present");
System.out.println(replaceTimes(pattern, "test:present", text, 2));
```

Comment: А какую роль здесь выполняет Pattern?

Comment: @mousecray роль регулярного выражения :)

Comment: Боже мой, это работает абсолютно так, как надо! Благодарю. Я думал об использовании regex, однако слишком плохо понимаю это. StringBuffer спасает от повторений, ведь так?

Comment: StringBuffer это просто инструмент для более эффективной сборки строки без полного копирования при каждой замене. Вся магия в `appendReplacement`/`appendTail`. Первая дополняет результирующую строку текстом при каждом совпадении, попутно делая замену, вторая копирует в результат оставшуюся часть входной строки без изменений.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пойду ещё раз почитаю про regex:)